# GPU Access for qiskit-aer-gpu from Ubuntu VM

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I have NVIDIA GeForce GT740 Graphics card installed on my host machine with Windows 10 OS. I have to simulate a cluster environment in order to run qiskit codes in parallel fashion. Before actual Clustering, as POC I have created three ubuntu 20.04 VMs (one head and two compute nodes) on my host machine since qiskit-aer-gpu can be easily installed on Linux. I have used VMWare Workstation Pro for the purpose.

Now on my head node I have created a venv and installed qiskit-aer-gpu along with CUDA

- python version: 3.8.10
- qiskit-aer-gpu version: 0.11.2
- nvcc version: Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

I am running following code as an example just to verify cuda installation on my VM but it generates error

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import *
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
sim = AerSimulator(method= 'statevector', device='GPU')
shots = 100
depth=10
qubits = 25
circuit = transpile(QuantumVolume(qubits, depth, seed=0), backend=sim, optimization_level=0)
circuit.measure_all()
result = execute(circuit,sim,shots=shots,seed_simulator=12345).result()
```

Error is

```
Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
ERROR: Failed to load qobj: No CUDA device available!
```

Ubuntu VM sees host GPU like `sudo lshw -C display`

```
-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: SVGA II Adapter
   vendor: VMware
   physical id: f
   bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=vmwgfx latency=64
   resources: irq:16 ioport:1070(size=16) 
   memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:fe000000-fe7fffff 
   memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have seen some article in which VM doesnot have direct access to host GPU [1](https://superuser.com/questions/299333/vmware-how-to-directly-access-the-gpu) and [2](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VM-have-direct-connection-to-the-host-GPU/td-p/1860425). Am I getting this no device error due to this reason?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an issue beyond `qiskit-aer-gpu`. To confirm or discard that, my to-go tool is PyTorch. Install `pip install torch` and run in a console:

```
from torch.cuda import is_available
is_available()
```

If `True`, submit an issue to `https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer` because it is, indeed, an Aer issue. If `False`, the problem is related to your environment and StackOverflow is probably a good place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure , but dont you have to install cuQuantum first ?
note:i cant comment due to my reputation number

Comment: Do i really have to? As cuQuantum is separate library from Nvidia and nothing to do with qiskit-aer-gpu. I have followed requirements from its github page